# Cypher query to return Markov Blanket

Tags: neo4j, cypher, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG with many nodes. I am looking for a cypher query to return the `Markov Blanket` of a given node.

ps: Markov blanket of A comprises of A's parents, A's children and its children's other parents.

[image]

Comment: create a sample dataset using http://console.neo4j.org and sketch exactly what the expected result of the query should look like

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know what format you want the data returned in, and I've invented Labels and a Relationship type but you can start from this:

```
MATCH (parent:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(a:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child:Person)
WHERE a.identifier = "theOneYouWant"
WITH a, parent, child
MATCH (otherParent:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
WHERE otherParent <> a
RETURN parent, a, otherParent, child
```

Answer (score 1):

Do all of the relationships have to exist?  i.e. Does **A** need to be a child? Does **A** need to have children? Does **A**'s children need to have other parents?

If some of the relationships are optional then I think you need to do something like this

```
match (a:A)
optional match (a)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(p1)
optional match (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(c)
optional match (p2)-[:PARENT_OF]->(c)
return *
```

This would return all of the parents, all of the children and all of the children's other parents.

Comment: `A` may not have parents and/or children. But yes, all the nodes and relations are of same type.

Comment: ok, well if all of the relationships are optional. i.e. even nodes at the periphery of the graph in your diagram have a markov blanket then I think the above cypher satisfies it.